# Walkabout Report Server URL and Stopped Service Application

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I've installed SQL 2012 in Sharepoint Integrated Mode and have Sharepoint 2010 installed on a different server. In Central Administration I have added a SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application and proxy. This all appears to have worked (the RS databases were created).

The problem is I cannot finish the configuration as I need the report server URL. Upon researching I found that this would be "http://myspserver/_vti_bin/reportserver" however this does not connect. I have looked at the rsreportserver.config file and where the URL should be is just

```
<ReportServerUrl>
</ReportServerUrl>
```

Upon looking at the at the service applications list I have noticed that the SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application is stopped. This might be why I can't connect to the URL so I tried stopping and restarting the SQL Server Reporting Services Service and although this was successful it made no difference to the state of the service application.

How to get this setup sorted out?